# Instanciar una cola implementada con generics con una clase

Tags: java, queue

tengo una pregunta que no se si puede ser un poco tonta. Tengo que implementar una cola con generics(ya lo hice) y a esa cola debo introducirle diferentes objetos de una clase que tambien tuve que implementar. El tema es que al usar la sintaxis para instanciar la pila me sale un error Bound mismatch, les dejo el codigo de como lo hice.

```
cola<Tripleta> colaTripleta = new cola<Tripleta>();
```

Tripleta es la clase de los objetos que quiero colocar en la pila y cola es la cola implementada con generics valga la redundancia

Les dejo mi implementación de la cola y de la clase Tripleta

```
public class cola<T extends Comparable<T>> {
private Node<T> head;
private Node<T> tail;

public cola(){
    this.head = this.tail = null;
}
public void encolar(T value){
    Node n_node = new Node(value);
    if(this.head == null && this.tail == null){
        this.head = this.tail = n_node;
    }
    else{
        this.tail.setNext(n_node);
        this.tail = n_node;
    }
}
public void desencolar(){
    if(this.head == null && this.tail == null) return;
    if(this.head == this.tail){
        this.head = this.tail = null;
        return;
    }
    this.head = this.head.getNext();
}
public boolean empty(){
    if(this.head == null)return true;
    else return false;
}
public T top(){
    return this.head.getValue();
}
```

}

```
public class Tripleta {

private String categoria;
private String nombreProducto;
private int numeroVeces;

public String getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
}

public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
}

public String getNombreProducto() {
    return nombreProducto;
}

public void setNombreProducto(String nombreProducto) {
    this.nombreProducto = nombreProducto;
}

public int getNumeroVeces() {
    return numeroVeces;
}

public void setNumeroVeces(int numeroVeces) {
    this.numeroVeces = numeroVeces;
}

public String toString(){
    return this.categoria+" - "+this.nombreProducto+" - "+numeroVeces;
}
```

}

Comment: Sube el código completo para que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: Ahi subi como implemente la cola y la clase tripleta

Answer (score 0):

La clase Tripleta no implementa Comparable por ese motivo se genera el error

```
public class cola<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

**<T extends Comparable<T>>** indica un limite para la clase Cola, ésta solo puede 'aceptar' tipos que sean de clase Comparable<T> o sus subtipos.

Puede generar confusión porque Comparable es una interfaz, pero en Generics *extends* se utiliza para indicar un limite superior a los parámetros de tipo que puede recibir una clase o función genérica. ( es lo que se conoce como *bounded type parameter*) y se utiliza para acotar el grupo de clases que pueden ser parametros de tipos para una clase,

(similarmente <T super C> es un limite inferior donde los parámetros de tipo solo pueden ser C u sus supertipos).

Explicado esto, el error *Bound mismatch* indica que la clase Tripleta no esta dentro de los limites permitidos.

```
public class Tripleta {
```

Agregando Comparable el error indicado se resuelve

```
public class Tripleta implements Comparable<Tripleta>{
```

No probé la implementación de la cola así que no se si funciona correctamente.